# Удаление сущности с Many To Many связкой

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, dao

В качестве ОРМ фреймворка используется Hibernate (через JPA). Есть метод по удалению сущности:

```
public void delete(final ID id) {
    entityManager.createQuery(String.format("delete from %s e where e.id = :id", entityClass.getSimpleName()))
    .setParameter("id", id).executeUpdate();
}
```

Удаляется сущность,которая связана Many To Many связкой с другой сущностью.

Вот логи Hibernate:

```
    Hibernate: delete from author_to_book where (author_id) in (select id from author where id=?)
    Hibernate: delete from author where id=?
```

Мне не понятно, как именно происходит удаление в этом случае, кто ответственен за удаление ассоциаций из таблицы-связки? Ведь в самом коде прописано удаление только из основной таблицы.

Comment: каким образом сущьности мапятся в бд?

Comment: У Author есть Set<Book> books

С таким маппингом:
    `@JoinTable(name = "author_to_book",
            joinColumns =  {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")} ,
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")}
    )

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Book.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

    private Set<IBook> books = new HashSet<>();`

У сущности Book нету маппинга на Author. В данном случае однонаправленная связь

Comment: А зачем ему мапинг на `Book` если у него многие-ко-многим?